# How to convert json array object to json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular6, lodash

** Scenario:**

- I am using lodash to remove the empty key from my JSON.
- But when it removes the keys it converts my array in an object for example

  ```
  {
  "projection": "Miller",
  "series": [
      {
          "mapPolygons": {
          "states": {
              "hover": {
                  "properties": {
                      "fill": "#67b7dc"
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      "heatRules": {
          "0": {
              "min": "#a82626",
              "max": "#AAAA00"              
          }
      },
      "data": {
          "0": {
              "id": "US",
              "value": 3461.37
          },
          "1": {
              "id": "DE",
              "value": 2858.09
          },
          "2": {
              "id": "NO",
              "value": 3418.87
          },
          "3": {
              "id": "ES",
              "value": 3522.46
          }
      }
  }
  ],
   "zoomControl": {
  "slider": {
      "height": 100
  }
  },
    "titles": {
      "0": {
      "fontSize": 20
      }
  },
  "homeZoomLevel": 1
  }
  ```

**Problem:**

If you see in the above code there is heatRules property which is an array after converting it is converted into object of 0, again if you see data attribute it does same if you see titles attribute it does same over there.

i have used below link code to remove empty object and null object:

[Why lodash converts my array into object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407174/why-lodash-converts-my-array-into-object)

Input Data:

```
    {
"projection": "Miller",
"series": [
    {
    "mapPolygons": {
    "states": {
        "hover": {
            "properties": {
                "fill": "#67b7dc",
                "size": ""
            }
        }
    }
},
"heatRules": [
     {
        "min": "#a82626",
        "max": "#AAAA00",
         "fill": null              
    }
],
"data": [
    {
        "id": "US",
        "value": 3461.37
    },
    {
        "id": "DE",
        "value": 2858.09
    },
    {
        "id": "NO",
        "value": 3418.87
    },
    {
        "id": "ES",
        "value": 3522.46
    }
]
}
],
     "zoomControl": {
"slider": {
    "height": 100
}
},
  "titles": [
   {
    "fontSize": 20,
   "fontColor": "" 
    }
],
"homeZoomLevel": 1
}
```

Output Data:

```
{
"projection": "Miller",
"series": [
    {
    "mapPolygons": {
    "states": {
        "hover": {
            "properties": {
                "fill": "#67b7dc"
            }
        }
    }
},
"heatRules": [
     {
        "min": "#a82626",
        "max": "#AAAA00"              
    }
],
"data": [
    {
        "id": "US",
        "value": 3461.37
    },
    {
        "id": "DE",
        "value": 2858.09
    },
    {
        "id": "NO",
        "value": 3418.87
    },
    {
        "id": "ES",
        "value": 3522.46
    }
]
}
],
     "zoomControl": {
"slider": {
    "height": 100
}
},
  "titles": [
   {
    "fontSize": 20 
    }
],
"homeZoomLevel": 1
}
```

If you see above output it removes null and blank key from properties -> size, heatRulues -> fill and from title it removes fontColor.

Comment: Please share your input sample data

Comment: and also the expected output.

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra i have provided input data.

Comment: @holydragon i have provided expected output too.

Answer (score 1):

If your code uses

`typeof v === 'object'`

it will return `true` for `arrays`.

To check for `array`, use

`Array.isArray(t)`

Treating `array` as `object` and iterating over keys will result in your issue.

## Sample Function To Recurse But Not Process Arrays

```js
function removeFalsies(obj) {
  return _.transform(obj, function(o, v, k, l) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj) {
          for (let arrItem of obj) {
            removeFalsies(arrItem);
          }
          return
        }
        // else not array...
      })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @steven-spungin could your please update in the function.

Comment: @Mayur I do no see a `function` in your question.  Are you referring to the linked answer?  If so, I added a modification that should process items in the array instead of the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS**

1. Iterate over heatRules property (since it is array so there might be multiple objects in there)
2. Iterate over the properties of each object in heatRules
3. Delete every property that has value of null

```js
let data = {
  "projection": "Miller",
  "series": [{
    "mapPolygons": {
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "properties": {
            "fill": "#67b7dc",
            "size": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "heatRules": [{
      "min": "#a82626",
      "max": "#AAAA00",
      "fill": null
    }],
    "data": [{
        "id": "US",
        "value": 3461.37
      },
      {
        "id": "DE",
        "value": 2858.09
      },
      {
        "id": "NO",
        "value": 3418.87
      },
      {
        "id": "ES",
        "value": 3522.46
      }
    ]
  }],
  "zoomControl": {
    "slider": {
      "height": 100
    }
  },
  "titles": [{
    "fontSize": 20,
    "fontColor": ""
  }],
  "homeZoomLevel": 1
}

data.series[0].heatRules.forEach(hr => {
  Object.keys(hr).forEach(p => {
    if (hr[p] === null) {
      delete hr[p]
    }
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Why lodash converts my array into object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407174/why-lodash-converts-my-array-into-object) e.g. and its working. check the code below.

```
let a = {
  "projection": "Miller",
  "series": [
    {
      "mapPolygons": {
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "properties": {
              "fill": "#67b7dc",
              "size": ""
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "heatRules": [
        {
          "min": "#a82626",
          "max": "#AAAA00",
          "fill": null
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "US",
          "value": 3461.37
        },
        {
          "id": "DE",
          "value": 2858.09
        },
        {
          "id": "NO",
          "value": 3418.87
        },
        {
          "id": "ES",
          "value": 3522.46
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "zoomControl": {
    "slider": {
      "height": 100
    }
  },
  "titles": [
    {
      "fontSize": 20,
      "fontColor": ""
    }
  ],
  "homeZoomLevel": 1
}

removeFalses = (obj)=> {
    return _.transform(obj, function (o, v, k) {

      if (v && typeof v === 'object' && !_.isArray(v)) {

        if (v !== '') {
          o[k] = removeFalses(v);
        }

      } else if(_.isArray(v)) {
  if(!o.hasOwnProperty(k)) o[k] = [];

  //And if it is array loop through it

  _.forEach(v, function(v1, k1) {
     o[k].push(removeFalses(v1));
  });

  }else if (v === false) {
        o[k] = v;
      } else if (v) {
        o[k] = v;
      }
    });
  }

console.log(removeFalses(a)) //desired output
```